# How can I port forward with iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

I want connections coming in on ppp0 on port 8001 to be routed to 192.168.1.200 on eth0 on port 8080.

I've got these two rules

```
-A PREROUTING  -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.200:8080

-A FORWARD -m state -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 8080 --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

and it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: [NAT HOWTO](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO.txt)

Comment: I'm going to go with the n-p-r tag (although this *could* be programming-related, though poorly phrased of course.)

Comment: How about this: I'm a programmer trying to set up an environment so I can debug my server application in eclipse being called from the innernet. Close enough?

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant by "poorly phrased"... Could you edit the question accordingly?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

First of all - you should check if forwarding is allowed at all:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ppp0/forwarding 
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding
```

If both returns `1` it's ok. If not do the following:

```
echo '1' | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ppp0/forwarding
echo '1' | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding
```

Second thing - `DNAT` could be applied on `nat` table only. So, your rule should be extended by adding table specification as well (`-t nat`):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ppp0 --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.200:8080
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Both rules are applied only to TCP traffic (if you want to alter UDP as well, you need to provide similar rules but with `-p udp` option set).

Last, but not least is routing configuration. Type:

```
ip route
```

and check if `192.168.1.0/24` is among returned routing entries.

Comment: I personally prefer the `sysctl` syntax like `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding=1`

Comment: How do I remove the incorrectly entered rule?

Comment: second line: "iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT" is NOT required if you don't have firewall restrictions/security, which is the case with most of home LANs, otherwise be careful with -A, be cause it will add it AFTER restrictions/security and may not work (so check -I instead, that is adding IN FRONT of iptables rules)

Comment: Will these rules be persisted if I reboot the computer?

Comment: @ÁronLőrincz, No. Iptables rules are volatile unless explicitly loaded at boot.

Comment: @Nickolai Leschov, enter same replacing `-A` with `-D`

Comment: iptables v1.8.7 sais `unknown option "--dport"`

Comment: ip: invalid argument 'nat' to 'table'

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov you gotta flush that table if you want to remove an incorrectly entered rule. `iptables -t nat -F` this will flush your nat table. (WARNING - you lose everything). I think if you want to target a specific rule, you may be able to do that too, someone. not sure how though.

Answer (score 18):

You forget postrouting source address SNAT 'ing:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
yours_wan_ip=101.23.3.1
-A PREROUTING  -p tcp -m tcp -d $yours_wan_ip --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.200:8080

-A FORWARD -m state -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 8080 --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -m tcp -s 192.168.1.200 --sport 8080 -j SNAT --to-source $yours_wan_ip
```

And don't forget to set your linux firewall as default gateway on computer with 192.168.1.200 address.

Comment: You got it backwards on the `POSTROUNTING` step. At this point the conversation is still about `--destination` rather than `--source`.

Comment: embeded system `-/bin/sh: sysctl: not found`

Answer (score 18):

The accepted solution works when the destination host and the gateway are on the ***same*** subnet (like is in your case, both are on `eth0` 192.168.1.0/24).

Below is a generic solution for when the gateway, source and destination are all on ***different*** subnets.

**1)** Enable IP forwarding:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding=1 
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding=1
```

<sub>//note: if forwarding to/from `localhost`, also set `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1`</sub>

---

**2)** Add 2 iptables rules to forward a specific TCP port:

To rewrite the *destination* IP of the packet (and back in the reply packet):

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -i ppp0 --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.200:8080
```

To rewrite the *source* IP of the packet to the IP of the gateway (and back in the reply packet):

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 8080 -j MASQUERADE
```

---

**3)** If you don't have a default `ACCEPT` firewall rule, allow traffic to the destination:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

---

**4)** Test the new setup. If it works, make sure the changes persist across reboots:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/sysctl.d/99-forwarding.conf
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding=1 
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding=1 
EOF

iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables.up.rules

echo '#!/bin/sh' > /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
echo "`which iptables-restore` < /etc/network/iptables.up.rules" >> /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables
```

Comment: I guess that should be the accepted answer because the others do not consider the POSTROUTING part which solves the problem of calling wanIP:8081 from the LAN.

Comment: This worked for me, first time, after months of flailing with various inferior alternatives.  Most excellent. I guess someone named "rusty" can be trusted when it comes to iptables... :-)

Answer (score 16):

I think what you want is:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state -p tcp -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 8080 --state 
    NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination
    192.168.1.200:8080
```

Comment: ummm... that IS what I have already. I use iptables-restore to load it so each is in its own section, but that's what I wrote above.

Comment: Okay, the syntax looked bad in the original.  Did you try -i ppp0 in the rules?  What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 9):

I have created the following bash script for doing this on my linux router. It automatically infers the WAN IP and confirms your selections before proceeding.

```
#!/bin/bash

# decide which action to use
action="add"
if [[ "-r" == "$1" ]]; then
  action="remove"
  shift
fi

# break out components
dest_addr_lan="$1"
dest_port_wan="$2"
dest_port_lan="$3"

# figure out our WAN ip
wan_addr=`curl -4 -s icanhazip.com`

# auto fill our dest lan port if we need to
if [ -z $dest_port_lan ]; then
  dest_port_lan="$dest_port_wan"
fi

# print info for review
echo "Destination LAN Address: $dest_addr_lan"
echo "Destination Port WAN: $dest_port_wan"
echo "Destination Port LAN: $dest_port_lan"
echo "WAN Address: $wan_addr"

# confirm with user
read -p "Does everything look correct? " -n 1 -r
echo    # (optional) move to a new line
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
  if [[ "remove" == "$action" ]]; then
    iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING  -p tcp -m tcp -d $wan_addr --dport     $dest_port_wan -j DNAT --to-destination $dest_addr_lan:$dest_port_lan
    iptables -D FORWARD -m state -p tcp -d $dest_addr_lan --dport     $dest_port_lan --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -s $dest_addr_lan --sport     $dest_port_lan -j SNAT --to-source $wan_addr
    echo "Forwarding rule removed"
  else
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp -m tcp -d $wan_addr --dport     $dest_port_wan -j DNAT --to-destination $dest_addr_lan:$dest_port_lan
    iptables -A FORWARD -m state -p tcp -d $dest_addr_lan --dport     $dest_port_lan --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -s $dest_addr_lan --sport $dest_port_lan -j SNAT --to-source $wan_addr
    echo "Forwarding rule added"
  fi
else
  echo "Info not confirmed, exiting..."
fi
```

The use of the script is simple just copy and paste it to a file and then.

```
# chmod +x port_forward.sh
# ./port_forward.sh 192.168.1.100 3000
... confirm details ... press y
# Forwarding rule added
```

To remove the same rule

```
# ./port_forward.sh -r 192.168.1.100 3000
... confirm details ... press y
# Forwarding rule removed
```

I thought this might save someone time on their respective router.

Answer (score 3):

I had the task to make MACHINE_A into thinking that the service is running physically on MACHINE_B, but transparently re-route all requests to MACHINE_C.

The trick was to use MASQUERADE.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d MACHINE_B --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination MACHINE_C

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s MACHINE_A -o INTERFACE_NAME -j MASQUERADE
```

Please note that you might want to tweak the commands:

1. To allow packet forwardning on a specific interface only. For example:

   ```
   sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding=1
   ```
2. To allow not only MACHINE_A, but also all others to use port forwarding, remove:

   ```
   -s MACHINE_A
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ppp0/forwarding
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding
```

These files tell the kernel it's allowed to forward packets between the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

This command doesn't work for me:

```
-A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -m tcp -s 192.168.1.200 --sport 8080 -j SNAT --to-source $yours_wan_ip
```

I have 2 LAN interfaces and FORWARD work when I'll written:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $LAN_IF -p tcp -m tcp --dport $FW_PORT -j SNAT --to-source $LAN_IP
```

- LAN_IF - LAN interface (eg. eth1, br0...)
- FW_PORD - forwarded port (on detination host)
- LAN_IP - IP address on LAN interface (on the router)

PREROUTING and FORWARD are necessary too, of course :)