# How to route UDP traffic from one public IP (linux) to another public IP(Windows)

Tags: ip, linux-networking, route, forwarding

I want to prevent direct access of my Windows Machine and want to expose some programs running on it via my Linux Machine (which again is accessible by a Public IP).

Is there a way where-in I can configure my Linux Machine (say IP = `a.b.c.d)` to route all the `UDP` traffic which it gets at a specific port (say `6667`) to my Windows Machine (say IP = `e.f.g.h`) at port `6668`?

Is yes, how can I implement it?

**UPDATE**

```
# bindadress    bindport  connectaddress  connectport

192.168.2.45    6667    192.168.2.104   6668

# logging information
logfile /var/log/rinetd.log

# uncomment the following line if you want web-server style logfile format
logcommon
~
```

**UPDATE**

I wish to route `UDP` traffic only.

Comment: Is the Linux machine the Windows machine's default router? Do you need replies to work too? Do you need the Windows machine to see the real source IP addresses of the UDP packets? (If the answers are "no", "yes", and "yes", you have a *very* hard problem.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The following section works for TCP only (This was published before Mahendra changed the title

Install rinetd. In this program you can configure incoming port and outgoing port easily.
First install the program. Then change /etc/rinetd.conf

Ex:

`#bindadress    bindport  connectaddress  connectport`

`a.b.c.d         6667      e.f.g.h        6668`

## For UDP check the link below

http://brokestream.com/udp_redirect.html

This is from the chat discussion which actually solved the problem

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $EXT_IF -p udp -d $EXT_IP --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination $INTERNAL_SERVER

and make sure you also have it allowed to pass through the FORWARD chain with something like

#forward traffic
iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXT_IF -o $INT_IF -p udp -d $INTERNAL_SERVER --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
#reply traffic
iptables -A INPUT -o $EXT_IF -i $INT_IF -p udp -s $INTERNAL_SERVER --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you.. this looks promising and easy to configure. Before I try it on my Live IP, I'd like to test it locally. Do you think this will work on local network as well?

Comment: yes of course. I've tested it

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but doesn't seem to work for me locally. I posted my conf file in the question...

Comment: Did you restart the rinetd.If not; restart it: /etc/init.d/rinetd restart

Comment: Yes, I restarted it.. doesn't work yet...

Comment: use telnet to verify the ports. ex: telnet 192.168.2.45 6667 is there a firewall in linux machine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4081/discussion-between-user637152-and-mahendra)

Comment: somebody downvoted it without explanation, please either put your comments or upvote it.. The answer really helped!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is called reverse NAT and is part of the IpTables capabilities of Linux. Every decent NATtins firewall does that to expose services.

Comment: Can you show me a working command line for reverse NAT?

Comment: No, I dont use Linux outside of firewall appliances and I doubt the setup instructions for a MIkrotik ROuterOs installation woudld mean anything to you or be helpfull at all, sorry.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables

Answer (score 1):

This is an [alternative UDP redirector for MacOS and Linux](https://github.com/danpodeanu/udp-redirect); in addition to the usual source / target, it supports specifying the source / destination interfaces, as well as dropping martians (UDP packets arriving from unknown sources).

You could run it as:

```
./udp-redirect \
   --listen-address 192.168.2.45 --listen-port 6667 \
   --connect-address 192.168.2.104 --connect-port 6668
```

Disclaimer: I am the author, and I am using it right now for this very post, to redirect Wireguard traffic.