# IPtables port forward

Tags: iptables

Scenario:

Using DDwrt on a linksys router. I want to port forward a specific public IP address to internal IP 192.168.0.20 port 80 using IPtables. Not sure how to do this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this: 

http://serverfault.com/a/140626/117969

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <public-ip> -i <wan-interface> -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.20
```

should work.  If you want to forward only TCP port 80 on the public IP, you can do:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -d <public-ip> -i <wan-interface> -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.20:80
```

Comment: Something like `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d <public-ip> -d <wan-interface> -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.20` to specify only port 80 traffic, otherwise that 192.168.0.20 will become the recipient of all traffic to the public IP.

Comment: Does'nt -d specify a destination address? Shouldn't that part be -s for the source address?

Comment: Nope.  From the NAT's perspective, the destination is the NAT box.  NAT in this case needs to change the destination to the host behind the NAT.  This all happens before the packet is routed.

Comment: So the answer provided will get any port 80 traffic coming from public ip forwarded to my private one?

Comment: The second command in my answer will.

Comment: Is it the only line that is needed or is a forward rule needed for the local interface?

Comment: It is all.  The first line would forward *all* incoming traffic to that local IP.