# forward public port 81 to port 80 on local ip

Tags: linux, iptables, redhat, port-forwarding

i am new to serverfault, so please inform me of any bad behaviors :)

i searched serverfault (and google) for an answer, but can't find the answer to my problem
(i can find answers which are partially what i need, but i lack the knowledge/experience to combine them to the solution to my problem)

the problem is as follows :
- i have a public server with port 81 which is available on the public ip address
- i have a local server with port 80 which is not available to the public
- i want the user to connect to port 81 on the public ip address and arrive at port 80 of the local server (192.168.98.###)

i think i need to do some configuring with iptables, but that's quite foggy to me

i tried some answers from [How can I port forward with iptables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables)
but i run into all kinds of errors

some questions :
- does the local server have to have some special configuration ? for example do i have to set the gateway to the ip address of the public server ?
- /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ppp0 doesn't exist, is that a problem ?

there are no ports blocked by the firewall

i have total control over the public server which is running on :

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.4.22-1.2115.nptl (bhcompile@daffy.perf.redhat.com) (gcc version 3.2.3 20030422 (Red Hat Linux 3.2.3-6)) #1 Wed Oct 29 15:42:51 EST 2003
# iptables --version
iptables v1.2.8
```

i don't know the os of the local server, and have no control over its configuration

could you please explain me which iptables settings i could use, or any other configuration ?

Comment: Really? You have total control over the server and you're running Fedora Core 1 on it?! That's out of the Dark Ages at this point.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : It's an old server (over 10 years old) which is still running perfectly. I could put a totally new OS on it, but the customer wants as little downtime as possible, and my motto is "don't fix when it ain't broken" :)

Comment: The problem is the local (video) server was available via the public address, but the customer changed their IP plan, and now the local server is in a different part of the network ... the customer themselves can access the local server via their internal network, but i would love to access it from the public as well for maintainance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, you don't need to deal with this `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ppp0`, if you are not running a modem on your gateway.

First thing you got to do, is to enable forwarding on your gateway like this:

```
# echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding (if you are running your live IP on eth0)
```

Then simply forward your traffic like this:

```
# iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:80
# iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

You should replace 192.168.1.2 with the internal IP of your machine. Also, replace `eth0`, with the interface on which you have the live IP on your gateway.

and at last, as given in the post you read earlier, you can check the routing with

```
# ip route
```

Hope this helped. Feel free to revert in case you face issue.

Also, please post the errors also which you get in this process.

Comment: sorry for the late comment : some other projects widged themselves into my priority list ... i will probably continue with this one in january ... thanks for you answer! it will be the first think that i will try, and i will let you know the results! ... hmm can't upvote you yet ... sorry .. will accept it as the answer when i tried it, and it works :)

Comment: Sure. Feel free to update in case of issues.