# How to open iptables ports inside a cluster?

Tags: iptables, centos6, linux

How can I use iptables to open ports 21001-22000 in a cluster, allowing the worker nodes to communicate between them and with the front-end?

The cluster is configured with CentOS 6.3, Rocks 6.1 and iptables 1.4.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command run as `root` will do that:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21001:22000 -j ACCEPT
```

Check the [`iptables(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) manpage for details.

Comment: @IVint67 Will this allow both **incoming** and **outcoming** traffic between workers and front-end?

Comment: @RSFalcon without more details, this is the best I can do for you. What connects to what with what?

Comment: @IVint67 As far has I understand this system: all nodes are connected in intern network (10.1.0.0/16), the only node with actual internet acess is the front-end (who has more than one network intercafe, one for the intern and other for external connection)

Comment: @RSFalcon7, I would update your question with that information. It sounds like you need [D]NAT and once done you will likely find your answers here: http://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables