# Configure squid to forward ftp requests to ftp server on some other machine

Tags: configuration, squid, vsftpd

I have installed `squid` proxy servers and `vsftpd` FTP server on 2 separate VMs. How can I Configure squid proxy servers on machines-A (where squid installed)to forward ftp requests to machine-B (where vsftpd installed)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). Squid can do caching but not port forwarding.

> Squid is a caching proxy for the Web supporting HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, and
>   more. It reduces bandwidth and improves response times by caching and
>   reusing frequently-requested web pages.

What you need to do is [port forwarding using iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables) that will forward ftp request on Machine-A to Machine-B.

For FTP proxying you may also try something like this: http://www.ftpproxy.org/