# Forward web requests to another IP and port over VPN

Tags: linux-networking, ip-forwarding

I have the following setup

`Web browser (192.168.5.10)` ——> `Home Ubuntu Server (192.168.5.15)` ————->`VPN over the internet`———>`to a public IP`——> `Work Server (192.168.6.90)` ——-> `Web interface at 192.168.6.90:8787`

On my Windows desktop after establishing the VPN tunnel between ubuntu server and work, I build an SSH Tunnel from the Home desktop to the Home Ubuntu server on port `9090`. Then using Firefox and SOCKS5 over `9090` I can connect to the work server and to the web interface at `192.168.6.90:8787`

Is it possible somehow to configure the ubuntu server so that every time someone connects from home via browser at 192.168.5.15:9090 this will be forwarded to 192.168.6.90:8787. In other terms to make the ubuntu server do the job of the SSH tunnel and SOCKS5 internally?

I tried port forwarding using

```
iptables --append FORWARD --protocol tcp --sport 8888 --dst 192.168.28.111 --dport 8787 --jump ACCEPT
iptables --append FORWARD --protocol udp --sport 8888 --dst 192.168.28.111 --dport 8787 --jump ACCEPT
```

But it didn’t work. Maybe I am doing something maybe this is not possible. I would appreciate any tip. I am not sure this is the right title for this question. I would appreciate any correction.

Comment: What you want to do is not FORWARDing but PREROUTING (with DNAT)

Comment: ok thank you. Could you please help me with the syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I port forward with iptables?](https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables)

Comment: unfortunately not